# How could I prompt for a value for the URL in Paw HTTP Client

Tags: paw-app

I have URLs like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/[ENV_VALUE_1]/items/[ENV_VALUE_2]/[ID]
```

The environment values are pre-defined and change when I change the context. But I'd like to prompt for the [ID] value on each request. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't possible yet. Would be a nice feature, though.

Comment: Mmmm... In this situations, what should I do with the question? Leave it unresolved?

Comment: Probably. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Do you have the ability to get the entire URL?  Do you have any kind of `Split` function?